# Typing Browser History in Vue JS 3 with Typescript

Tags: typescript, eslint, vuejs3

I'm getting the "unsafe member access .forward on an 'any' value" from eslint when accessing the browser history state:

```
if(!previousTab && window.history.state.forward === '/docs') {
  restoreTab()
}
```

How do you type the browser history with VueJS 3 and Typescript to remove the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [create an object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) for your history state:

```js
interface HistoryState {
  forward: string;
}
```

And assert that on `window.history.state`:

```js
if (!previousTab && (window.history.state as HistoryState).forward === '/docs') {
  restoreTab()
}
```